# Passing a variable to a lambda-function

Tags: php

How to pass a variable "$field" to a lambda-function?

```
function implode_assoc_array($array, $field)
{
    // $ids = array_column($array, $field); PHP 5.5!
    $ids = array_map(function($item) { return $item[$field]; }, $array);
    return implode(', ', $ids);
}

implode_assoc_array($my_multidimensional_array, 'id');
```

Message: Undefined variable: field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
array_map(function($item) use($field) { return $item[$field]; }, $array);
```

see the example http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: u'r welcome, glad can help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function implode_assoc_array($array, $field)
{
    // $ids = array_column($array, $field); PHP 5.5!
    $ids = array_map(function($item) use ($field) { return $item[$field]; }, $array);
    return implode(', ', $ids);
}

implode_assoc_array($my_multidimensional_array, 'id');
```

If you want to modify the variable use

```
    $ids = array_map(function($item) use (&$field) { return $item[$field]; }, $array);
```

See [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), Example #3 Closures and scoping